# How to use .p7b for Root CA in Ubuntu

Tags: openssl, certificates

I need to add a *p7b root ca* to Ubuntu, in order to connect to services/servers for my company.

Based on what I have found on the internet, it seems that I need to convert this file to either `.crt` or `.cer`. I used the following commands to convert the file:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in cert.p7b -out cert.cer
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in cert.p7b -out cert.crt
```

I then moved these files (I actually tried them one at a time) into `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mycompany`, and then added `mycompany/cert.cer` and `mycompany/cert.crt` to the `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`. After performing `update-ca-certificates` I still get root CA warning that the certificates/chain isn't in the system.

The only direction my company has given is for both Windows and adding this file into the OSX keychain. Any help is appreciated, because I don't like disabling https while using remote services/tools for my company.

Comment: Are you getting the CA error in your web browser?  Or where does it appear?

Comment: I am attempting to connect to a server via a VMware application.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar situation, may be this helps. I have received a certificate in `.p7b` format. First, I converted it into `.pem` format. Then, I imported it into Firefox (or your browser). After that, I could access my application using that certificate.

Now, in order to convert a `.p7b` into `.pem` do as follows.

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in yourCert.p7b -print_certs -out yourCert.pem
```

Hope this helps.